# Finding the region a world map coordinate belongs to in Dwarf Fortress

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I am trying to find the region a given world map coordinate belongs to in Dwarf Fortress.

A Dwarf Fortress world defines a large number of geographical regions, each associated with a biome and a number of world map positions. These can be reviewed in the "legends" game mode, are displayed when selecting an embark location and are enumerated in the "Legends Viewer" 3rd party utility. The Legends Viewer utility also allows you to overlay a region on the world map to see where it is located.

For my use case, I need to perform the opposite lookup. Given a world map coordinate, how do I find the region(s) that occupy that coordinate?

Using Legends Viewer, if a coordinate also contains a site, I can find that site on the "World Map" tool and then find out which region that site belongs to but this option isn't always available. It is also possible to find this information directly in Dwarf Fortress while selecting an embark location, but this screen is not available when a game is already in progress in that world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3rd party utility [Legends Browser](https://github.com/robertjanetzko/LegendsBrowser) provides this functionality.

In the World Map tab, enable the "Regions" overlay (top right). This overlay draws an outline of each region on the world map. Hovering with the mouse over each region displays that region's name and biome as a tooltip, and the name is a hyperlink to the region's legend entry.